# Different settings based on control variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, global-variables

OK, what I need is rather straightforward but I'm looking for the best, CodeIgniter-friendly, solution :

- I've got a website based on CodeIgniter
- I've got a local copy; when the local copy is edited, an online/live version is also updated

**What I need :**

- Have it "detect" whether I'm running from Localhost or from the real server, and set up e.g. Database details accordingly (preferably by setting some "global" variable).

So, any ideas? How would you go about it?

Comment: Have both db configs in the CI config, you can select which settings to use when you connect to the database. Not a solution for detection, but I wanted to point out this is probably the best way to have access to either DB when using whatever method you decide on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use:

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'localhost'){
    //local settings
} else {
    //live settings
}
```

Comment: OK, that's correct. It works fine. However, I still have one more question : what if I also want to use a different `.htaccess` depending on settings? (= if on localhost, use *this*; otherwise, use *that*)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon - Afraid I can't help you with that.

Comment: OK, no problem at all; just found a solution for that too : http://wordpress.org/support/topic/success-mapping-multiple-domains-to-different-folders-with-htaccess

Comment: Sidenote : Not that relevant, and I'm not so... lusophone either, but I simply *love* your username. :-) Thanks again, buddy! :-)